# SQL case statement dependent on other rows in result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have some data that comes out of a cube.

[image]

I have one row in this order that has gone in as a substitution variance but I need to put it in the quantity variance bucket. The code that decides on whether it's a substitution is here at the lowest level (this is within a large CTE) (The code behind this cube is massive and exists on multiple levels)

```
CASE 
   WHEN ISNULL(PC.ItemDimCostPrice, SC.ItemDimCostPrice) = 1
        AND (PC.ConfigId <> SC.ConfigId
             OR PC.InventColorId <> SC.InventColorId
             OR PC.InventSizeId <> SC.InventSizeId
             OR PC.InventStyleId <> SC.InventStyleId) 
      THEN 1
      --New code here ... THEN 0
   WHEN PC.[Resource] IS NULL
        OR SC.[Resource] IS NULL 
      THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END AS [HasSubstitutionVariance] ,
```

The logic that they have given me which i need to add into this is basically if the cost grouping is material (i know how to calculate this) and there exists another record with the same costgroupid and operationid (within the production order) then this will never be a substitution variance.  I was thinking of using rownumber and partitioning on costgroupid and operationid but as far as i'm aware you can't use window functions in a case statement?  Anyone have any ideas how I would do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Do what? It is completely unclear what you are talking about.

Comment: mark substitution variance as 0

Comment: Didn't read the whole question, but in SQL when you want to do a CASE expression that involved a value from a different row in the same table, you need to use either a sub-query or self-join to get the value of that other row.

Comment: The query this case statement is in is HUGE.  I don't want to have to repeat it in a sub query... there must be another way?

Comment: Lag and lead, cte will help you to reuse code.

Comment: Put the whole query in a cte and you don't have to repeat the whole query, just repeat the name of the cte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what i came up with.  Was fairly straightforward actually.  So as I stated in the post that code was in a CTE.  I left that code alone, later in the CTE I added

```
CASE WHEN MC.HasSubstitutionVariance = 1
                      AND ( COUNT(MC.CostGroupId) OVER ( PARTITION BY MC.ProdId,
                                                         MC.CostGroupId,
                                                         MC.OprId ) > 1
                            AND LEFT(MC.CostGroupId, 3) IN ( 'LAB', 'FOH',
                                                             'L T', 'F T' )
                          ) THEN 0
                 ELSE MC.HasSubstitutionVariance
            END AS HasSubstitutionVariance ,
```

Which says is the costgroup repeated and is it standard material, if so mark substitution variance as 0.  I thought you couldn't use OVER within a CASE statement?  Or is it only certain window functions you can't use within CASE?